# retrieve record from database using latitude longitude distance mysql join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, distance

I found lots of similar posts but nothing comparable to my problem.

I've connected two tables in my database while retrieving distance using latitude and longitude.

Specificly, these are my tables:

```
registeredUsers:
publicSSID, nome, cognome, eta, sesso, foto, informazioni
```

*(translating: publicSSID = univoque id, nome = name, cognome = surname, eta = age, sesso = sex, foto = photos, informazioni = informations)*

```
position:
ssid, latitude, longitude
```

*(ssid = publicSSID -> same things)*

this is my query:

```
SELECT publicSSID, nome, cognome, eta, sesso, foto, position.latitude, 
    position.longitude, informazioni, (3956 * 2 * 
      ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($lat - abs(latitude))*pi()/180/2),2)
      +COS($lat*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(latitude)*pi()/180)
      *POWER(SIN(($lon-longitude)*pi()/180/2),2)))) 
      as distance 
      FROM registeredUsers, position 
      WHERE registeredUsers.publicSSID = position.ssid
      and longitude between ($lon - 1/abs(cos(radians($lat))*69)) 
      and ($lon + 1/abs(cos(radians($lat))*69)) 
      and latitude between ($lat -(1/69)) 
      and ($lat +(1/69)) 
      having distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 200;
```

where `$lat`, `$lon`, `$dist` are respectively my input latitude, longitude and the distance in km I use to retrieve records. So for example, if there are two records with latitude and longitude that we know are within 10 kilometers of distance, if i set `$dist = 10`, the database has to return me those two records.

Now the problems are lots.

First of all, saying that the `$lat, $lon` are also stored in the table `position` ***(because who is trying to do this request is a user who wants to find another user near to himself)*** and I don't want it to retrieve myself (lol), but at the moment with that query I retrieve ONLY my record (so myself, I retrieve the latitude and longitude equals to `$lat, $lon`).

I tried to edit it and I've deleted this row:

```
WHERE registeredUsers.publicSSID = position.ssid
```

So the query now is:

```
SELECT publicSSID, nome, cognome, eta, sesso, foto, position.latitude, 
    position.longitude, informazioni, (3956 * 2 * 
      ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($lat - abs(latitude))*pi()/180/2),2)
      +COS($lat*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(latitude)*pi()/180)
      *POWER(SIN(($lon-longitude)*pi()/180/2),2)))) 
      as distance 
      FROM registeredUsers, position 
      WHERE longitude between ($lon - 1/abs(cos(radians($lat))*69)) 
      and ($lon + 1/abs(cos(radians($lat))*69)) 
      and latitude between ($lat -(1/69)) 
      and ($lat +(1/69)) 
      having distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 200;
```

And now the NEW problem is that it retrieves all the people around me (including myself) but it change every latitude and longitude (in the result not in the database) overwriting it with the latitude and longitude in `$lat,$lon`.

What can I do? Do somebody know a way to retrieve what I want using this kind of **Join** for mySQL?

Thank you

Comment: 2 questions:
1. if you calculate the distance and make sure you get only results that fall within that required distance, why do you also limit latitude and longitude in your where clause? 2. (related)  what is the meaning of the 69 constant you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be late, but it looks like the first query do exectly what you want. Just remove some strange conditions and get all the users that are close to the specified point:

```
SELECT publicSSID, nome, cognome, eta, sesso, foto, position.latitude, 
    position.longitude, informazioni, (3956 * 2 * 
      ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($lat - abs(latitude))*pi()/180/2),2)
      +COS($lat*pi()/180 )*COS(abs(latitude)*pi()/180)
      *POWER(SIN(($lon-longitude)*pi()/180/2),2)))) 
      as distance 
      FROM registeredUsers, position 
      WHERE registeredUsers.publicSSID = position.ssid
      having distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 200;
```

If you want to exclude the user, who executes the query just pass it's id as a param and a condition like  registeredUsers.publicSSID <> $currentuserid.

Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33f96d/1/1 is a model of you query

(I had to hardcode $lat = 10, $lon = 10, and two dfferent $dist - 1000 and 10000)